# Asus laptop not booting up. No BIOS, blank screen, power indicator on

Tags: asus-laptop

Last night, I switched off my Asus K73SV. In the morning, When I pressed the power button, I just saw the power indicator and a blank screen.

I tried reattaching both of my RAMs, I even tried taking out the battery and pressing the power button for 30 sec but din't help.

I can see indicating light on the power button and above the bulb icon on my laptop. The hard drive and all other indicators are off....I can't even hear the fan moving.

Here are my specs- 
Quad-Core i7-2670QM @ 2.2 Ghz
8GB(4+4) DDR3 Memory
750GB + 750GB HDD
Nvidia GT540M 1GB

I've not overclocked it and never did anything too smart. I'm asking here because ASUS support takes days to reply. Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

Is your laptop giving any other indications that it is booting? Try booting with the battery removed and the power cable inserted. Try tapping F2 to get to the BIOS or F9 to get to recovery menu (if the recovery partition is intact)

Comment: No signs of life. Just the power indicator...i'll check getting into the BIOS though i don't think it will work because the screen is dead and nothing shows up

Comment: If you remove both RAM sticks and try to power it on, does it beep at you?

If the fan isn't spinning up at all, just the power light, and you've already eliminated the RAM as a potential cause, you are probably looking at a component failure, not just a BIOS issue. If you're dead-set on not working through ASUS' support (and I don't blame you--they're awful), I'd try opening it up, and checking the connections of any expansion cards (wireless/video), the seating of the CPU and heatsink, and the connections of all cables. Be careful, though; take the HD out first.

Answer (score 0):

Plug the laptop in but remove the battery. This will indicate if the battery has anything to do with this.